# Change tmp-directory used by Landscape?

Tags: landscape

If i understand correctly, Landscape uploads all scripts as files before they run, and they are stored under /tmp. This is of course a problem if you configure tmp partition with noexec, and leaves me with an error similar to this:

```
     File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 598, in _execvpe
     exec_func(file, *argrest)
          PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/tmpnn0rb1qz'
```

So, is it possible to change the location Landscape uses to store the scripts? I couldn't find such option for landscape-config, and nothing in the config files.

I really dont want to configure tmp with exec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really supported by Landscape so we will have to patch the file:

1. Open `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/client/manager/scriptexecution.py` in a text editor
2. Replace the `fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()` line with `fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(dir="/path/to/where/you/want/to/store/the/scripts")`
3. Reboot
4. Reapply these changes whenever you upgrade the `landscape-client` package